# Disable see-through view mode in SketchUp

Tags: sketchup

I pressed something and enabled a see-thorough mode in SketchUp. I ended up with the geometry being displayed like it is cut by some invisible plane.

I don't want it, how can I disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your geometry is still ok and you only have activated a section plane. In View menu you can make the section plane visible for example to move it and in the same menu you can disable the section cuts.

Refer to user's guide how to use the sections cut views.

In the following image I'm trying to place a section plane. It's taken to use from the Tools menu:

[image]

Now it's placed and the view is rotated to see the section.

[image]

The plane is visible, but it's easy to switch off in the view menu. The cut still remains, if it's not shut down. Maybe this is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're having trouble with an automated camera clipping plane, which isn't something you can manually control - use the zoom extents button, which looks like a magnifying glass with arrows pointing outwards from it.

[image]

This resets the camera to show your entire model, and from there you can zoom back in with no clipping planes; this will become part of your regular SketchUp workflow routine - happens *all* the time.